# Store constant values in java application, gwt or android apps

Tags: java, android, gwt

I would like to discuss the ways and the benefits of them to store the constant values in a java application. What is the best way to store constant values?
I am now using the interface to store them.

```
public interface AppConst {
    final String testport="8080";
final String http="http";
final String sitesUrl = "http://" + serverIp + ":" + testport + "/sitesServlet";
}
```

Some people store these constants as environment variables and read them in by annotation.
Is there any other way to do it?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

When you extract a literal value like your site URL you are adressing issues of modifiability, binding time, and readability.

Instead of changing the valie at every position in your code, you only need to change the field/interface/config file, etc. If the value is only used inside one class, it is fine to define a static field inside that class. If it is used by several classes, I would prefer the interface over a public (or default visibility if all classes reside in the same package) field for clarity.

Binding time: If the user or operator has to be able to change the value, which I would guess is the case for your site URL, you need the value to be defined at start-up or during the runtime of your application. So you need a place outside your code, e.g. a config file, environment variable, database, or even an editor within the application. The choice depends on your use case: e.g. if the value is set by a script it may be easier to use a config variable. If the value is to be versioned (e.g. the installation is part of a delivery pipeline) a config file may be better.

The last issue is readabiliy: a call `saveFile(name, READ_ONLY)` is better readable than `saveFile(name,0)`.